# Sending to RESTful service JSON with file pointer resource

Tags: php, json, rest, file-pointer

I'm trying to figure out how to send this kind of data, via PHP, to a RESTful service:

```
{
  "api_version": 1.0,
  "project_id" : 123,
  "batch_id" : 111,
  "accesskey" : "abc123",
  "job": {
    "file": file,
    "word_count": 111,
    "title": "FAQ",
    "cms_id": "page_123_en_sp",
    "url" : "http://original_post_url.com",
    "is_update": false, 
    "translator_id": 123,
    "note": "Translate these words",
    "source_language": "en",
    "target_language": "it"
  }
}
```

First of all, I cannot use curl, as who's going to use this code might not have it installed or might be not allowed to install it.

That's not a 'normal' JSON object.
The job->file property is an actual file (not even an url to a file).

That's the actual code I'm using to send all requests and it worked, until I've met this specific case: http://pastebin.com/6pEjhAkg

The 'file' property is created as such:

```
$file = generate_file( $content );

protected static function generate_file($content) {
    $file = fopen('php://temp','r+');
    fwrite($file, $content);
    rewind($file);
    return $file;        
}
```

Now, when sending data, with $params argument properly set on PHP side, the RESTful returns an error about missing 'api_version' and 'project_id', but they are present.
I'm pretty sure the problem is that he's not receiving data as JSON, but how can I convert to JSON an object that, in his properties, contains a file pointer resource?

The code that sends data and builds the file has been created by a former developer, and I can't get in touch with him.

I tried to understand what is wrong there and the only thing I managed to fix so far, for another unrelated issue, is to actually send JSON data (when $multipart==false), as you can see in lines 16-19 of the linked code, rather than sending urlencoded data.

Any hint?

Comment: If it is "not a 'normal' JSON object" then it is not JSON. Are you sure the server can deal with it?

Comment: Apparently yes. I've been in touch with the developer, who said they ran unit tests for all the APis. I'm trying to get in touch with them again, to see how did they send the content, but it's not easy, dure to different time zones. To be honest I've called this 'not normal', but I'm not sure if it is or not: I don't have much experience with RESTful service and I have no idea if this way to send data is even possible, but it looks like: until I get more information from the developer, I must take for granted that it is possible to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSON does not have a "file" concept. You can either load the file content, encode it using Base64 and then stuff it into a JSON string - or you can use multipart format for sending the file in one part and the complete JSON in another part. The multipart solution should be the best performing as it doesn't have to base64 encode the file content.

Here is a similar example message format from [Mason](http://soabits.blogspot.dk/2014/02/representing-issue-tracker-with-mason.html) that tries to formalize the json/multipart usage:

```
POST /projects/2/issues HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/vnd.mason+json
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=d636dfda-b79f-4f29-aaf6-4b6687baebeb

--d636dfda-b79f-4f29-aaf6-4b6687baebeb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment"; filename="hogweed.jpg"
... binary data for attached image ...

--d636dfda-b79f-4f29-aaf6-4b6687baebeb
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="args"; filename="args"
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "Title": "Hogweeds on the plaza",
  "Description": "Could you please remove the hogweeds growing at the plaza?",
  "Severity": 5,
  "Attachment":
  {
    "Title": "Hogweed",
    "Description": "Photo of the hogweeds."
  }
}
```

Comment: Eventually I had to give up sending data as JSON (only for multipart posts), and go back to the initial Content-Disposition: form-data method. This way it works. Anyway @jorn-wildt is the better answer I could find (and I even implemented it, but the server on the other side really seem to expect data in a different format, when there are attachments involved).